# prove or disprove $n > 0 ~\rightarrow~\prod \limits_{i=1}^{n} \left ( \frac{1}{2i~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2i~+~2} \right ) ~=~ \frac{1}{(2n~+~2)!}$

Tags: induction

I am working on one of my HW assignments
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, ~
 n > 0
 ~\rightarrow~
 \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n} \left (
  \frac{1}{2i~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2i~+~2}
 \right )
 ~=~
 \frac{1}{(2n~+~2)!}
$$
And i am not clear whether it should be proved or disproved.
my main concern is base case n=1.
$$P_r (1) =  \frac {1}{(2*1+1)}+\frac{1}{(2*1+2)} = \frac{1}{12}$$
$$P_l (1) =  \frac {1}{(2*1+2)!}= \frac{1}{24}$$
but prove for k+1 works

Induction Hypothesis
$$  \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n} \left (
  \frac{1}{2i~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2i~+~2}
 \right )~=~
 \frac{1}{(2n~+~2)!} \rightarrow  \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \left (
  \frac{1}{2i~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2i~+~2}\right )~=~
 \frac{1}{(2(n+1)~+~2)!} = \frac{1}{(2n+4)!}
$$

$$  \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \left (
  \frac{1}{2i~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2i~+~2}\right ) = \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n} \left (
  \frac{1}{2i~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2i~+~2}
 \right )\cdot  \left (
  \frac{1}{2(n+1)~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2(n+1)~+~2}
 \right )
$$
by substitution
$$   = \frac{1}{(2n~+~2)!}\cdot  \left (
  \frac{1}{2(n+1)~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2(n+1)~+~2}
 \right )
$$

$$  = \frac{1}{(2n+2)!}\cdot  
  \frac{1}{2n+3} \cdot \frac{1}{2n+4} = \frac{1}{(2n+4)!}
$$

Now why my base case isn't working? if it should work for all n>0

Comment: The problem is that the result is false: the left-hand side is twice the right-hand side. The product on the left should run from $i=0$ to $n$, not from $i=1$ to $n$. This doesn’t affect the induction step, but it does make it impossible to establish the base case.

Answer (score 0):

$P = \dfrac{1}{3\cdot 5\cdots \cdot (2n+1)}\cdot \dfrac{1}{4\cdot 6 \cdots (2n+2)} = \dfrac{1}{3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdots \cdot (2n+1)(2n+2)} = \dfrac{1}{\frac{(2n+2)!}{2}}= \dfrac{2}{(2n+2)!}$

Comment: the left part has no factorials in it, only right part. But I understand that $$(2n+1)\cdot (2n+2)$$ will equal to $$ (2n+2)!$$ BUT why the base isn't working out?

Comment: its not working because for $n =1, LHS = \dfrac{1}{12} \neq \dfrac{1}{24}= RHS$

Comment: will disprove it with existential statement
$$ \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}, ~
 n > 0
 ~\rightarrow~
 \prod \limits_{i=1}^{n} \left (
  \frac{1}{2i~+~1} \cdot \frac{1}{2i~+~2}
 \right )
 ~\neq~
 \frac{1}{(2n~+~2)!}$$